# Toggle comment shortcut while using a custom syntax highlighter

Tags: sublimetext3

I tried creating a custom syntax for Sublime. I have this line included from their tutorial:

```
contexts:
  main:
    - match: '//'
      scope: punctuation.definition.comment.example-c
      push:
        # This is an anonymous context push for brevity.
        - meta_scope: comment.line.double-slash.example-c
        - match: $\n?
          pop: true
```

This is matching comments in my script exactly as expected. However, the shortcut I've been using for Toggle Comments On/Off (Command+/) is not working. Is there a way to make the Toggle Comments shortcut work with the custom syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meta information regarding what a comment is doesn't come from the syntax, it comes from [meta information](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/metadata.html) in a `tmPreferences` file which you also have to create yourself.

Following on the example syntax above, that would look like this (change the `scope` to the appropriate top level scope as needed):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>name</key>
  <string>Comments</string>
  <key>scope</key>
  <string>source.example-c</string>
  <key>settings</key>
  <dict>
    <key>shellVariables</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
        <key>value</key>
        <string>// </string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>TM_COMMENT_START_2</string>
        <key>value</key>
        <string>/*</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>TM_COMMENT_END_2</string>
        <key>value</key>
        <string>*/</string>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
  <key>uuid</key>
  <string>1d23fd10-e62f-4de8-a8d1-42e64e3f5fb7</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The name you give the file doesn't matter, only the extension (and that it be saved in a Package; put it in your `User` package if you don't have a specific package going already). The common convention is something like `Comments.tmPreferences` in the root of the package that contains the syntax.

This shows two things; first, that there can be more than one `TM_COMMENT_START`-type item, and that it can also optionally be paired with a matching `TM_COMMENT_END` item.

When used singly, such as `TM_COMMENT_START`, the comment is a line comment, while when used in a pair you're specifying that the comment is a block comment that needs a beginning and ending pair.

Sublime uses one or the other depending on the arguments to the command that generates the comments, if possible. So if there are two defined (as here) then you get a line comment unless there is selected text, in which case you get a block comment.

If there is only a line comment or a block comment defined, you only get that style of comment and nothing else. This is why HTML only comments blocks and treats single lines as blocks, for example.

Note also that there can be an arbitrary number of `TM_COMMENT` items/pairs, but Sublime will only use the first one of each type automatically. Plugins that you write can access the others, though.